# How to trigger build in TFS from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, tee

I have installed Jenkins in Unix box and I am trying to trigger a build i.e. initiating BuildDefinition present in TFS project. I am new to this so I am not sure how to trigger BuildDefinition from jenkins.

Note: I am able to checkout the source file present in TFS from jenkins. Also i installed TEE-CLC-12.0 in Jenkins Unix box.

Please help!!!

Comment: Could you explain your need for Jenkins in this scenario? Why not just use a TF Build?

Comment: BTW: TFS 2015 has a node build agent that runs on Linux!

Comment: Install TFS plugin and you can select the Poll SCM checkbox which will trigger build after every check-in.